# SQL Key - detect differences in case

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, primary-key, case-sensitive

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to host a database. I have a value that has 3 columns: id, name, and value. I have one entry with the name of "Active". I want to add another (different) entry with the name "ACTIVE" but get an error:

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '[table name]' with unique index
>   'IX_[table name]'. The statement has been terminated.

What do I need to do to fix this? I want to be able to add 'ACTIVE', not not 'Active'.

Comment: Case sensitivity is determined by the collation for the database.

Comment: @RickS Do you know the option in the collation it is?

Comment: There are many case sensitive collations

Comment: You can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but I don't have any recommendation for you.

Comment: I like to use case sensitive collations for lookup tables. Especially when the user front end will have them choosing from a dropdown. If you allow Multiple values with the same name it is incredibly confusing. "Which Active should I choose??". This looks a lot like a lookup table to me.

Comment: @RickS I believe the collation is what needs to be changed. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanLange it's not :)

Comment: What's not? It isn't a lookup table? Be careful about changing collation. There are times when this isn't going to do what you want. Sometime there is code that finds rows using ToLower or ToUpper which will not work when you allow multiple values that are the same when case sensitivity is removed.

Comment: Case-sensitivity of a column is determined by the *column* collation, not the database collation. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190920.aspx